# Make conditional drop effect according to dragged widget?

Tags: drag-and-drop, zk

According to document, I can make custom drop effect by overriding

```
Widget.dropEffect_(boolean)
```

However, I cannot make a widget display different drop effect according to dragged widget, because there is no reference of the dragged widget available.

My question is :

**How do I make a drop effect that can changes according to dragged widget ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override getDrop_ function to log the current dragged widget,

e.g.,

```
zk.afterLoad("zul", function () {
    var _wgt = {};
    zk.override(zk.Widget.prototype, _wgt, {
        getDrop_: function (dragged) {
            zk.Widget.currentDraggedInstance = dragged;
            return _wgt.getDrop_.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    });
});
```

see the sample at zkfiddle for more information

[custom drop effect](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/120dc43/2-custom-drop-effect)

Comment: I am not asking how to use `dropEffect_()`. My question is, how do I make a widget have different drop effect according to dragged widget ?

Comment: I am somewhat worry about the global reference, but this code dose exactly what I want. Thank you.